# Ionic simple href not working on android device

Tags: android, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this very simple `HTML` :

```
<div> <a href="http://google.com" onclick="alert('test2');">CLICKKKKK</a></div>
```

The `alert` is showed when user click the `anchor`, but it never redirect/open the `href` link on android device.

The `href` is working when tested on browser (`ionic serve`)

Please kindly help me, Thanks a lot

**UPDATE**

This is my `cordova plugin list` :

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.7 "Keyboard"
```

And i have added this in my `config.xml` :

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

But still the `href` wont work on the android device

**UPDATE 2**

I tried :

```
<div> <a href="" ng-click="open()">CLICKKKKK</a></div>
```

With the controller :

```
app.controller('someCtrl', ['$scope','$window',function ($scope, $window) {
      $scope.open = function() {
          $window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_system');
        }
    }
]);
```

But it still work only in browser, not in actual device.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the culprit :)

Its because i commented this single code in my `index` :

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Muhsin Thanks a lot for your help :) It seems you sent a wrong project

Comment: But what if we're using push notifications and the ionic-platform-web-client plugin automatically comments that script injection? Would uncommenting the injection break the push functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

**HTML**

```
<div> <a href="" ng-click="open()">CLICKKKKK</a></div>
```

**Contoller**

```
$scope.open = function() {
    $window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_system');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added that plugin, please kindly see my updated question

Comment: <div> <a href="" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_system');">CLICKKKKK</a></div>

Comment: Thanks. I tried your `window.open`, its working on the browser but not in the android device.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you get the href working on the actual device? I tried your code but its still not working (again, only working on the browser). Please kindly see my code in the updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94707/discussion-between-muhsin-and-blaze-tama).

Comment: @Muhsin is there any difference between '_system' and '_blank' ?